# SQL - How to extract multiple attributes from XML field within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to run a SQL query on a table which has one field that contains XML data, but that XML contains multiple values that need to be pivoted into the one field. Please note that the field is XML content but the actual field type is set to nvarchar(max), not xml.

Edit: Version is **SQL Server 2014 Express Edition**

I have a table like this:
[List of Customers with Markets]

[image]

And I want to extract the 'marketCode' values in the same row (comma delimited):

```
|CompanyCode|CompanyName|MarketCode,MarketCode,MarketCode,etc.|Phone|
```

Expected output from example (see screenshot):

```
|ABC123|JOHN DEERE|AA,BB,CC,DD|555-123-000|
|DEF456|NEW HOLLLAND|AA,FF,GG,HH,KK|555-456-0000|
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample data**

Please provide text instead of images next time ;-)

Column `Markets` is defined as `nvarchar(max)`. Data is inserted as unicode (with `N` prefix).

```
create table Company2
(
    Code nvarchar(6),
    Name nvarchar(11),
    Markets nvarchar(max),
    Phone nvarchar(12)
);

insert into Company2 (Code, Name, Markets, Phone) values
(N'ABC123',
 N'JOHN DEERE',
 N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <license>
    <company companyCode="ABC123">
      <markets>
        <market marketCode="AA"/>
        <market marketCode="BB"/>
        <market marketCode="CC"/>
        <market marketCode="DD"/>
      </markets>
    </company>
  </license>',
 N'555-123-0000'),
(N'DEF456',
 N'NEW HOLLAND',
 N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <license>
    <company companyCode="DEF456">
      <markets>
        <market marketCode="AA"/>
        <market marketCode="FF"/>
        <market marketCode="GG"/>
        <market marketCode="HH"/>
        <market marketCode="KK"/>
      </markets>
    </company>
  </license>',
 N'555-456-0000');
```

**Solution**

Casting `Markets` directly to `XML` is not possible because the `nvarchar(max)` encoding conflicts with the "utf-8" in the data. I moved the conversion into a separate common table expression (CTE, `cte_convert`), going from `nvarchar(max)` to `varchar(max)` to `XML`.

The next CTE (`cte_parse`) can now use `c.MarketsXML.nodes()` to fetch the `<market>` nodes from the XML into a new column `m.Market`. From that column the `@marketCode` attribute is extracted as the desired value.

A subquery with `for xml path('')` is then used to concatenate the values.

```
with cte_convert as
(
    select c.Code, c.Name, convert(XML, convert(varchar(max), c.Markets)) as MarketsXML, c.Phone
    from Company2 c
),
cte_parse as
(
    select c.Code, c.Name, m.Market.value('@marketCode', 'nvarchar(10)') as MarketCode, c.Phone
    from cte_convert c
    outer apply c.MarketsXML.nodes('/license/company/markets/market') as m(Market)
)
select  cp.Code,
        cp.Name,
        stuff(( select ',' + cp2.MarketCode as MC
                from cte_parse cp2
                where cp2.Code = cp.Code
                for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') as MarketCodes,
        cp.Phone
from cte_parse cp
group by cp.Code, cp.Name, cp.Phone;
```

**Result**

```
Code   Name        MarketCodes    Phone
------ ----------- -------------- ------------
ABC123 JOHN DEERE  AA,BB,CC,DD    555-123-0000
DEF456 NEW HOLLAND AA,FF,GG,HH,KK 555-456-0000
```

---

This original solution uses the [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function which is available starting from SQL Server 2017.

**Sample data**

Remark: the column `Markets` is defined as `XML` to reflect its content.

```
create table Company
(
    Code nvarchar(6),
    Name nvarchar(11),
    Markets XML,
    Phone nvarchar(12)
);

insert into Company (Code, Name, Markets, Phone) values
('ABC123',
 'JOHN DEERE',
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <license>
    <company companyCode="ABC123">
      <markets>
        <market marketCode="AA"/>
        <market marketCode="BB"/>
        <market marketCode="CC"/>
        <market marketCode="DD"/>
      </markets>
    </company>
  </license>',
  '555-123-0000'),
('DEF456',
 'NEW HOLLAND',
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <license>
    <company companyCode="DEF456">
      <markets>
        <market marketCode="AA"/>
        <market marketCode="FF"/>
        <market marketCode="GG"/>
        <market marketCode="HH"/>
        <market marketCode="KK"/>
      </markets>
    </company>
  </license>',
  '555-456-0000');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte_parse as
(
    select c.Code, c.Name, m.Market.value('@marketCode', 'nvarchar(10)') as MarketCode, c.Phone
    from Company c
    outer apply c.Markets.nodes('/license/company/markets/market') as m(Market)
)
select cp.Code, cp.Name, string_agg(cp.MarketCode, ',') as MarketCodes, cp.Phone
from cte_parse cp
group by cp.Code, cp.Name, cp.Phone;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff2c833614f93265511d3f253800f8bf)

Comment: if the market column is nvarchar but holds a XML string, wrap it with a convert(xml, market).value... other than that, nice use of string_agg!

Comment: @Mitz, as there is `encoding="UTF-8"` in the *xml declaration* (`<?xml blah blah ?>`), this would not work... Either use `VARCHAR` (1-byte encoding) together with `utf-8` or `NVARCHAR` (2-byte encoding) with `utf-16` (or `ucs-2`). Best was to 1) store XML in the native type or at least 2) store the XML without the declaration...

Comment: @Shnugo your're right. If the insert can be controlled that is the best choice. I've had some cases where i had no control over the inserts and had to manually strip the declaration with a replace(...); but all my xml files were < 4k characters so it was not very costly... This is life when interfacing with some uninterested state employees ^^

Comment: @Sander, thanks for your detailed response. So it looks like the SQL version I have is  SQL Server 2014 Express Edition, and STRING_AGG only works on SQL 2017 and later.

Is there a different way of performing the STRING_AGG function?

Also, the native field of the XML is actually NVARCHAR(max), not XML, so I think this needs to be CAST as well?

Comment: @JustinS, new solution provided without the function `string_agg()`, with data type `nvarchar(max)` and the required casts.

Comment: @Sander, that second process with the STUFF is now working for me. Thanks for all your effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(CompanyMarkets nvarchar(max));
insert into @t(CompanyMarkets)
values(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<license>
<company companyCode="ABC123">
<markets>
<market marketCode="AA"/>
<market marketCode="BB"/>
<market marketCode="CC"/>
<market marketCode="DD"/>
</markets>
</company>
</license>');

select
    --remove encoding ...
    try_cast(replace(CompanyMarkets, 'encoding="UTF-8"', '') as xml),
    --... or transform any prolog to a weird&harmless processing instruction 
    try_cast(concat(case when CompanyMarkets like N'<?xml%' then '<?x ' end, CompanyMarkets) as xml) 
from @t;


select *,
    try_cast(concat(case when CompanyMarkets like N'<?xml%' then '<?x ' end, CompanyMarkets) as xml).query('
    for $i in (data(/license/company/markets/market/@marketCode)[1], (for $k in data(/license/company/markets/market/@marketCode)[position()>1] return concat(",", $k)))
    return text {$i}
    ').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    
    --?? no spaces in marketCodes
    replace(
    try_cast(concat(case when CompanyMarkets like N'<?xml%' then '<?x ' end, CompanyMarkets) as xml).query('data(/license/company/markets/market/@marketCode)').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    ' ', ','),
    
    stuff(
    try_cast(concat(case when CompanyMarkets like N'<?xml%' then '<?x ' end, CompanyMarkets) as xml).query('
    for $i in data(/license/company/markets/market/@marketCode) return text {concat(",", $i)}
    ').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

from @t;
```